# Adding two numbers in php and retaining leading zeroes

Tags: php

I need to add numbers in php without changing the number format like below

```
$a = "001";  
$b = "5";  
$c = $a+$b;
```

Now the result comes like "6" but I need "006" if `$a` is "01" then the result should be "06".

Thanks

Comment: Numbers do not have a "format", only a numeric value. You'll need to format your numeric values with however many leading zeros you want when you *output* them. Mathematical operations do not know about formatting.

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeroes..... you need to do your addition, and then format to display leading zeroes using something like str_pad()

Comment: count the length of both numbers (as strings), save the largest. Add the numbers up, check the length of the result, add zeros to match the largest length.

Comment: Please define the result for `001 + 999`, should that be `1000`, `000` or `001000`?

Answer (score 4):

Technically speaking, the `$a` and `$b` in your example are [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) - when you use the addition operator on them they converted to [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) which can't retain leading zeroes. More [details on string-to-number conversion are in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Something like this would do it (assuming positive integer strings with leading zeros)

```
#figure out how long the result should be
$len=max(strlen($a), strlen($b));

#pad the sum to match that length
$c=str_pad($a+$b, $len, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

If you always know how long the string has to be, you could use [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf), e.g.

```
$c=sprintf('%03d', $a+$b);
```

Here, `%` introduces a placeholder, `03` tells it we want zero padded to fill at least 3 digits, and `d` tells it we're formatting an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help you:

```
<?php
$a="001";
$b="5";
$l=max(strlen($a),strlen($b));
$c=str_pad($a+$b, $l,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $c;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For common case. Your code should looks like this.

```
$a = someFormat($original_a);
$b = someFormat2($original_b); // $b has different format.
$c = someFormat($a + $b);
```

Or, you need write formatRecognition function.

```
$a = getValueA();
$b = getValueB();
$c = someFormat(formatRecognition($a), $a + $b);
```